# C#: Goal is to create a 4x4 sudoku game. I have to read lines of a .txt file and store contents in an array

Tags: c#

```
private void form_load()
    {

        char[] numbersArray = new char[16];


        try {

            StringBuilder lines = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("config.txt"))
            {
                lines.Append(line);
            }
            numbersArray = lines.ToString().ToCharArray();


            for (int counter =0;counter < 15;)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(numbersArray[counter].ToString());
                counter++;
            }


            /*StreamReader inputFile = new StreamReader("test.txt");
            while (counter < numbersArray.Length && inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                numbersArray[counter] = char.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
                counter++;
            }
            inputFile.Close();
            */
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

My question is how do I read a .txt file that looks like this.

1254006984520016

5249646549864165

5464651465413652

and store it into a 2d char array.

I'm not looking for a handout of already created program, but I've tried the list collection, and string builder and stream reader but can't get those to work like I was expecting. I'm fine with going about this a different way but not sure where to go from here.

the char array, {0,0-15} should be one line then {1,0-15} should be another line. but the first element amount is unknown, but the lines will always be 16 char long.

Thanks

Comment: Start by changing `[15]` to `[16]` .

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing *2d array* `char[,]` to *jagged* one `char[][]` and with a help of *Linq* you'll have

```
 char[][] numbersArray = File
   .ReadLines("config.txt")
   .Select(line => line.ToCharArray())
   .ToArray();
```

When your goal is just to read file you usually don't want `Stream`s and `StringBuilder`s